# flash creates more than one http request

Tags: flash, http, macos

We are facing one issue directly connected with our Flash API we've given to a 3rd party flash vendor.
To make a long story short, our API basically wraps domain logic on client and creates a single POST request towards the server in JSON format.

All will be ok except in combination MacOS + Safari we receive **double requests on server** (?).

Even more interesting, we are receiving different agent names - one is expected name/decriptor of the browser and system, other is "CFNetwork".

```
POST /RuntimeDelegate.ashx - 80 Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+U;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_4_11;+fr)+AppleWebKit/531.22.7+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/4.0.5+Safari/531.22.7 200 0 0
POST /RuntimeDelegate.ashx - 80 CFNetwork/129.24 200 0 0
POST /RuntimeDelegate.ashx - 80 Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+U;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_4_11;+fr)+AppleWebKit/531.22.7+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/4.0.5+Safari/531.22.7 200 0 0
POST /RuntimeDelegate.ashx - 80 Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+U;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_4_11;+fr)+AppleWebKit/531.22.7+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/4.0.5+Safari/531.22.7 200 0 0
POST /RuntimeDelegate.ashx - 80 CFNetwork/129.24 200 0 0
POST /RuntimeDelegate.ashx - 80 Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+U;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_4_11;+fr)+AppleWebKit/531.22.7+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/4.0.5+Safari/531.22.7 200 0 0
POST /RuntimeDelegate.ashx - 80 CFNetwork/129.24 200 0 0
POST /RuntimeDelegate.ashx - 80 CFNetwork/129.24 200 0 0
```

Has anyone encounter anything like this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From various reading it appears that CFNetwork is responsible for things like grabbing the favicon, bookmarks, and other resources.

I wonder if that mac has your handler bookmarked.

Interesting:
http://www.webmasterworld.com/search_engine_spiders/3783085.htm

and another interesting bug post for something very similar:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19530

Lately, the #1 browser that's given me problems is safari.  I thought after version 4 it would be better, but it's still a pos.

Comment: It would be really really good if this would be fixable in some other way than updating 2 years old bug report :(